# I have some JavaScript function that keeps repeating itself, I can't find why

Tags: javascript, html

This is code that generates a selected image when a function is run, but the image keeps changing, I want this code to let me have one image and keep it that way instead of it changing randomly every `0.5` - `3` seconds, and I don't know why!

```
const imageSelector = document.querySelector("#changeHeron")
function spinMachine() {
    document.getElementById('spinner').disabled = 'disabled';
    spinner.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    setInterval(enterBall, 1000)
    var protmt = prompt("What's your name?")
    alert("Hey there " + protmt + ", " + "its great to see you here")
}
function enterBall() {
    var ball = document.getElementById("changeHeron");
    ball.style.opacity = "100%";
    ball.style.transform = "ScaleX(50%) ScaleY(50%)";
    setInterval(liftBall, 1000);
}
function liftBall() {
    var ball = document.getElementById("changeHeron");
    ball.style.transform = "translateY(-250%)";
    ball.style.transform = "ScaleX(200%) ScaleY(200%)";
    ball.style.top = "40%";
    setInterval(changeImage, 1500);
}


function changeImage() {
    var images = ["./Images/Football.png", "./Images/Mousetache.png", "./Images/OG.svg"];
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var ball = document.getElementById("changeHeron");
    ball.src = images[randomNum];
    ball.style.borderRadius = "5%";
    ball.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: Dont worry I have now found a way around this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can place the images varible outside and change it inside when the code has ran so that the rest can just work outside of this problem